# How to buy Benefactor Schafter

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to buy a Benefactor Schafter in Offline mode (so I won't lose the car if I destroy it). I can't find it on the both Online Shops for cars. Is there any way to buy the car?

Answer (score 1):

It can be found at the Golf Club Carpark. That is a spawn location for the vehicle. I'm not sure it can be bought anywhere.